# Git ignores credentials stored in .git-credentials

Tags: git, credentials

I have two local repositories which are hosted on the same server and I have configured Git to store my credentials in the .git-credentials file via the following command.

```
git config credential.helper store
```

However, the fetch/pull/push without entering credentials only work in one repository. In the other repository, Git always asks for credentials and ignores the .git-credentials file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have solved my problem. My config command was missing the global option. Without this option I have only configured it for one repository.

The correct command would have been:

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```